# Using R to plot onto 1 axis value

Tags: r, ggplot2

Not sure how to word my question, so this is what I'd like a quick plot to look like, ignore the awful axis lines and border:

[image]

And this is what my data looks like, very basic:

[image]

I assigned the symbols to the fields where I want the green or red symbols with this:

```
status_agged$status[status_agged$current_avg > status_agged$abc_avg] <- 2
status_agged$status[status_agged$current_avg < status_agged$abc_avg] <- 6
```

I'm lost now where to begin my plotting function to plot all on 1 line. I should be able to get the small things resolved myself, like gridlines and colors.

(And I know this isn't the best use-case for R, but my other tool doesn't have this functionality)

Output of dput(status_agged):

```
structure(list(category = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Activities Transition", 
"Arrival Logistics and Greetings", "Organization of Activity", 
"Schedule and Offering", "Space Adequacy"), class = "factor"), 
    CurrentAvg = c(4, 2.75, 3.86666655540466, 3.79999995231628, 
    3), ABCAvg= c(3.819841, 3.469858, 3.725926, 3.358, 3.577333
    ), PLGAvg = c(3.69721, 3.439394, 3.638, 3.306087, 3.454638
    ), status = c(2, 6, 2, 2, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you post the output of `dplut(df)` of your dataframe? Its hard to work with images of the data since we have to type it

Comment: You can just set the x value to a constant. `ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Category)) + geom_point()`. Using built-in data as an example, `ggplot(iris, aes(x = '', y = Species)) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do

```
status_agged$status <- as.factor(status_agged$status)
ggplot(status_agged, aes(x = "", y = category)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = status, color = status, shape = status), size = 10, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("6" = 25, "2" = 24)) + theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("6" = "red", "2" = "green")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("6" = "red", "2" = "green")) + xlab(NULL)
```

[image]

In addition to what is said in the comments, I set shapes 24 and 25 according to your picture (they have both `fill` and `color` aesthetics).

Comment: Hmm I'm getting the error `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale` and I tried setting the shape with `shape=as.factor(status)` but no luck. What do I need to adjust?

Comment: @simplycoding, removing `factor` from the data definition gives me this error, but then `as.factor` fixes it. So possibly you changed something else. Having `dput(status_agged)` would solve all problems.

Comment: Added the output of `dput(status_agged)`. I should have worded that first comment better - after getting the error, I then added in `shape=as.factor(status)` also to other variables but with no luck

Comment: Nvm, got it working somehow. Not sure what I did differently

Comment: @simplycoding, great, it does indeed work with your data for me too.

Comment: If I want to add another field for setting the color and fill of my shapes, do they need to be set as `factor` as well? I've added a field to the dataframe - tried both hex codes and character strings like black or white but no luck.

Comment: @simplycoding, see the update. Yes, they need to be factors because you want to use a discrete scale.